# mysql count with group runs very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, count

I have the following tables
`awarded_companies`, `tenders`, `grants`.

There are 2 many-to-many relationships

1. `awarded_companies <-> tenders`
2. `awarded_companies <-> grants`

I want to list all awarded companies which belongs to a tender.

So the query looks like this:

```
SELECT awarded_companies.*
FROM awarded_companies
JOIN awarded_company_tenders ON (awarded_company_tenders.awarded_company_id = awarded_companies.id)
GROUP BY awarded_companies.id
```

Actually I have tons of records and need to paginate the result. When I try to count all the `awarded_companies` that belongs to a `tender` the query takes 30 sec.

Here are some benchmark of the 2 ways of counting the rows and the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`:

1. [Count with subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmcz2.png)
2. [Count distinct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btr8G.png)

The only thing that I can come up is to add a 2 flags to `awarded_companies` - one to tell if the company belongs to a `tender` and second to tell if the company belongs to a `grant`.

This way I'll be able to remove the `join` and the `group by` and the query will look like this:

`SELECT * FROM awarded_companies WHERE has_tender=1`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you have indexes on `awarded_companies(id)` and `awarded_company_tenders(awarded_company_tenders)`? This would speed up the query not having to look up the values in a table but rather perform a lookup on index structures.

Comment: Yes of course. I can share the schema if you want.

Comment: Please add `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` before your `SELECT` and update your question with the result.

Comment: I've updated the images attached to the links. You can see the `EXPLAIN` below the query.

Comment: You have not shown us your `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; perhaps you are missing some of the tips in [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count (awarded_companies.id)
FROM awarded_companies
JOIN awarded_company_tenders ON (awarded_company_tenders.awarded_company_id = awarded_companies.id)
GROUP BY awarded_companies.id

Comment: Here are the benchmark - http://bit.ly/21iweZw.
Actually, in that case there is no difference if you're doing `select count(*)` or `select count(awarded_companies.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. Is there is any logical issue in directly selecting the count from 'awarded_company_tenders'. Do we have to start from 'awarded_companies' and join 'awarded_company_tenders' for finding count.

Comment: Yes, we have to start from `awarded_companies` because this whole thing is part of CMS, and I have to list all `awarded_companies` which belongs to `tenders`. I have to be able to filter `awarded_companies` by `country` or `location`, or anything else. As you might know, the pivot table can tell me the count of all `awarded_companies`.

Comment: Can you please check the performance of this one?   SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM awarded_company_tenders
JOIN awarded_companies ON (awarded_companies.id = awarded_company_tenders.awarded_company_id)
GROUP BY awarded_companies.id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  awarded_companies AS ac
    WHERE  EXISTS 
      ( SELECT  *
            FROM  awarded_company_tenders
            WHERE  awarded_company_id = ac.id 
      )
```

Notes: By avoiding the `JOIN` (which exploded the number of rows), the `GROUP BY` (which imploded) is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I've added 2 flags and the query is running super fast.

Thanks everyone for the comments.